# Код выводящий картинку в код который выводит видео

Tags: php, css

У меня есть код который выводит картинку [image: В разделе изображение, напротив выгрузилась картинка на скриншоте]

Теперь возникает вопрос, можно ли переделать или модифицировать код который выгружает картинку, так чтобы он мог выводить видео формата mp4?

Ниже предоставлен код который позволяет загружать изображение

```
<?php

class Product
{
    // подключение к базе данных и имя таблицы
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "products";

    // свойства объекта
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $price;
    public $description;
    public $category_id;
    public $image;
    public $timestamp;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    // метод создания товара
    function create()
    {
        // запрос MySQL для вставки записей в таблицу БД «products»
        // запрос
$query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
    SET name=:name, price=:price, description=:description,
        category_id=:category_id, image=:image, created=:created";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // опубликованные значения
        $this->name = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
        $this->price = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->price));
        $this->description = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->description));
        $this->category_id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->category_id));
        $this->image = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->image));

        // получаем время создания записи
        $this->timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        // привязываем значения
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":price", $this->price);
        $stmt->bindParam(":description", $this->description);
        $stmt->bindParam(":category_id", $this->category_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(":created", $this->timestamp);
        $stmt->bindParam(":image", $this->image);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function countAll()
  {
      // запрос MySQL
      $query = "SELECT id FROM " . $this->table_name . "";

      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute();

      $num = $stmt->rowCount();

      return $num;
  }
  // метод для получения товаров
  function readAll($from_record_num, $records_per_page)
  {
      // запрос MySQL
      $query = "SELECT
                  id, name, description, price, category_id
              FROM
                  " . $this->table_name . "
              ORDER BY
                  name ASC
              LIMIT
                  {$from_record_num}, {$records_per_page}";

      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute();

      return $stmt;
  }
  // метод для получения товара
  // метод для получения товара
  function readOne()
  {
      // MySQL запрос
      $query = "SELECT name, price, description, category_id, image
          FROM " . $this->table_name . "
          WHERE id = ?
          LIMIT 0,1";

      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
      $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);
      $stmt->execute();

      $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      $this->name = $row["name"];
      $this->price = $row["price"];
      $this->description = $row["description"];
      $this->category_id = $row["category_id"];
      $this->image = $row["image"];
  }
// метод для обновления товара
function update()
{
    // MySQL запрос для обновления записи (товара)
    $query = "UPDATE
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                name = :name,
                price = :price,
                description = :description,
                category_id  = :category_id
            WHERE
                id = :id";

    // подготовка запроса
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // очистка
    $this->name = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
    $this->price = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->price));
    $this->description = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->description));
    $this->category_id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->category_id));
    $this->id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));
    $this->image = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->image));

    // привязка значений
    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
    $stmt->bindParam(":price", $this->price);
    $stmt->bindParam(":description", $this->description);
    $stmt->bindParam(":category_id", $this->category_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $this->id);
    $stmt->bindParam(":image", $this->image);

    // выполняем запрос
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// метод для удаления товара
function delete()
{
    // запрос MySQL для удаления
    $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE id = ?";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

    if ($result = $stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
// выбираем товары по поисковому запросу
public function search($search_term, $from_record_num, $records_per_page)
{
    // запрос к БД
    $query = "SELECT
            c.name as category_name, p.id, p.name, p.description, p.price, p.category_id, p.created
        FROM
            " . $this->table_name . " p
            LEFT JOIN
                categories c
                    ON p.category_id = c.id
        WHERE
            p.name LIKE ? OR p.description LIKE ?
        ORDER BY
            p.name ASC
        LIMIT
            ?, ?";

    // подготавливаем запрос
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // привязываем значения переменных
    $search_term = "%{$search_term}%";
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $search_term);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $search_term);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $from_record_num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    // выполняем запрос
    $stmt->execute();

    // возвращаем значения из БД
    return $stmt;
}
// метод для подсчёта общего количества строк
public function countAll_BySearch($search_term)
{
    // запрос
    $query = "SELECT
            COUNT(*) as total_rows
        FROM
            " . $this->table_name . " p
        WHERE
            p.name LIKE ? OR p.description LIKE ?";

    // подготовка запроса
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // привязка значений
    $search_term = "%{$search_term}%";
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $search_term);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $search_term);

    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $row["total_rows"];
}
// загрузка файла изображения на сервер
function uploadPhoto()
{
    $result_message = "";

    // если изображение не пустое, пробуем загрузить его
    if ($this->image) {

        // функция sha1_file() используется для создания уникального имени файла
        $target_directory = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_directory . $this->image;
        $file_type = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        // сообщение об ошибке пусто
        $file_upload_error_messages = "";
    }

// проверяем, разрешены ли определенные типы файлов
$allowed_file_types = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "mp4");

if (!in_array($file_type, $allowed_file_types)) {
    $file_upload_error_messages .= "<div>Разрешены только файлы JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF.</div>";
}

// убеждаемся, что файл не существует
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $file_upload_error_messages .= "<div>Изображение уже существует. Попробуйте изменить имя файла.</div>";
}

// убедимся, что отправленный файл не слишком большой (не может быть больше 1 МБ)
if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > (10485760)) {
    $file_upload_error_messages .= "<div>Размер изображения не должен превышать 1 МБ.</div>";
}

// убедимся, что папка uploads существует, если нет, то создаём
if (!is_dir($target_directory)) {
    mkdir($target_directory, 0777, true);
}
// если $file_upload_error_messages всё ещё пуст
if (empty($file_upload_error_messages)) {

    // ошибок нет, пробуем загрузить файл
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        // фото загружено
    } else {
        $result_message .= "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
            $result_message .= "<div>Невозможно загрузить фото.</div>";
            $result_message .= "<div>Обновите запись, чтобы загрузить фото снова.</div>";
        $result_message .= "</div>";
    }
}

// если $file_upload_error_messages НЕ пусто
else {

    // это означает, что есть ошибки, поэтому покажем их пользователю
    $result_message .= "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
        $result_message .= "{$file_upload_error_messages}";
        $result_message .= "<div>Обновите запись, чтобы загрузить фото.</div>";
    $result_message .= "</div>";
}
    return $result_message;
}
}
```

В нем прописываются условия загрузки, я туда добавил в форматы поддерживаемых типов файлов mp4.

```
<!-- HTML-таблица для отображения информации о товаре -->
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Название</td>
        <td><?= $product->name; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Рейтинг</td>
        <td><?= $product->price; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Описание</td>
        <td><?= $product->description; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Категория</td>
        <td>
            <?php // выводим название категории
            $category->id = $product->category_id;
            $category->readName();

            echo $category->name;
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Изображение</td>
    <td>
        <?= $product->image ? "<img src='uploads/{$product->image}' style='width:300px;' />" : "Изображение не найдено."; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php // подвал
require_once "layout_footer.php";
```

Но в итоге после того как попробовал загрузить видео в формате mp4 ошибок не выдало но и видео не отображается [image: Загрузил файл mp4 и ошибок не выдало]

Но после открытия Страницы со всей информацией, вместо видео там иконка как на скрине [image: иконка напротив раздела изображение]

Comment: Очевидно, что тег `img` не предназначен для вывода видеофайлов.

Comment: Можно подробнее описать тему вставки видеофайла, я в этой сфере начинающий, может у вас примеры есть какие-то?

Comment: [<video>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)